Kafka message order while processing the message
In Kafka there are 3 topics, but the messages are like order ready, ship and pickup.. There are huge requests coming for these messages. These messages are related to each other, so how do you make sure that these messages are processed in an order? Any other suggested design patterns to solve this use case? Thanks ...
